# Convert img link to bitmap

Tags: android, imageview

I have this code to convert image link to the bitmap and show in Imageview

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageLink).getContent());
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

everything is ok but if my link contains space " " for example:
UserUpload/Image/Mercedes Benz.jpg

my imageview doesn't show the bitmap.!?

whats wrong with this ?

Comment: try `URL url = new URL(imageLink.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));`

Comment: you are not deleting the space you are [http url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your URL:

```
String imageLink = "http://domain.com/UserUpload/Image/Mercedes Benz.jpg";
URL url = new URL(imageLink);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```